# Caesar cipher - Trouble with negative numbers in the shift key

Tags: c#, encryption, visual-studio-2019

When I use a negative number for the shift like -1 and use the char 'a', I'm supposed to get 'z' but I get ` instead. How can I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CaesarCipher
{
    class Program
    {
        public static char cipher(char ch, int key)
        {

            if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
            {

                return ch;
            }

            char d = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
            return (char)((((ch + key) - d) % 26) + d);
        }

        public static string Encipher(string input, int key)
        {
            string output = string.Empty;

            foreach (char ch in input)
                output += cipher(ch, key);

            return output;
        }

        public static string Decipher(string input, int key)
        {
            return Encipher(input, 26 - key);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool Continue = true;

            Console.WriteLine("      Ceasar Cipher");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------\n");

            while (Continue)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nType a string to encrypt:");
                    string UserString = Console.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write("\nShift: ");
                    int key = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("\nEncrypted Data: ");

                    string cipherText = Encipher(UserString, key);
                    Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
                    Console.Write("\n");

                    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Data:");

                    string t = Decipher(cipherText, key);
                    Console.WriteLine(t);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to continue?");
                    Console.WriteLine("Type in Yes to continue or press any other key and then press enter to quit:");
                    string response = Console.ReadLine();
                    Continue = (response == "Yes");
                }
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a bad operation, try another one");
                }



            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Ceasar Cipher

Type a string to encrypt:
Hello how are you?

Shift: 1

Encrypted Data:
Ifmmp ipx bsf zpv?

Decrypted Data:
Hello how are you?

Do you want to continue?
Type in Yes to continue or press any other key and then press enter to quit:
Yes

Type a string to encrypt:
Hello how are you?

Shift: -1

Encrypted Data:
Gdkkn gnv `qd xnt?

Decrypted Data:
Hello how `re you?

Do you want to continue?
Type in Yes to continue or press any other key and then press enter to quit:

Comment: The answer seems obvious enough: You need a rollover. The English alphabet is only about 26 Characters wide. If you go below or above that, you need to return to the other end. You should consider making a array with the characters, rather then just doing ASCII math. Not only will that support more languages, you will avoid small letters turning into big or vice versa with large offsets. Only +/-7 can turn a small 'a' into a big 'Z'. IIRC Romans did not use small letters, so they had less of an issue with that.

Comment: `return (char)((((ch + key) - d) % 26) + d);` is equivalent to: `return (char)(ch + key);`, which is not, I guess, what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

` is the character that proceeds "a" in the ASCII/Unicode character list. https://unicode-table.com/en/

You'll want to detect if you're trying to shift "a", and instead replace it with "z"

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do this. One way would be to subtract from the last letter the difference if the result is less than the first letter:

```
public static char cipher(char ch, int key)
{
    if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
    {
        return ch;
    }

    char firstLetter = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
    char lastLetter = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'Z' : 'z';

    int result = ch + key;

    if (result < firstLetter) result = lastLetter - (firstLetter - result + 1);

    return (char)result;
}
```